# Python, Django - loaddata issue "RemovedInDjango18Warning"

Tags: python, django

I have a local python environment working, but when I try and load in initial data.

python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json
I get an error about "RemovedInDjango18Warning"?

I am not a python dev to say - so this error is new to me.

```
C:\Python27\aasoo>python manage.py loaddata initial_data.json
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djorm_pgfulltext\models.py:323: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `SearchManagerMixIn.get_query_set` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.
  class SearchManager(SearchManagerMixIn, models.Manager):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\modeltranslation\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 50, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*fixture_labels, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 61, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 91, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 142, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 81, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 75, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 122, in Deserializer
    m2m_data[field.name] = [m2m_convert(pk) for pk in field_value]
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Python27\aasoo\content\fixtures\initial_data.json': 'int' object is not iterable

C:\Python27\aasoo>
```

Comment: Which version of Django/Python are you using? Also, what apps did you include in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Oh, also it seems like the Django warning has nothing to with it. It's failing due to the DeserializationError... Is your json file formatted properly?

Comment: I'm using python27. Need to check the django version - the json seems fine - I've run it through projsonlint - seems to be good

Comment: Overseer is right. The warning is not causing an issue. Paste the json file and the model files for which you are loading the data for.

Comment: django version 1.7.1

Comment: @TheOldCounty: try making the change Vijay suggested and see if anything changes. If not, paste your json, models and settings in the question and we'll see.

Comment: I made the change vjay said - it stopped that error bug - but didn't load the json data - the problem above still persisted

Comment: @TheOldCounty: Could you paste the new error traceback please. It would really help. Also, edit the question and include your json, models and settings file.

Comment: Sorry guys. I can not. I've been terminated by the client anyhow, and they have breached the contract without serving 24 hour notice. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename get_query_set to get_queryset in SearchManagerMixIn. Can you paste the definition of the class if you need more help.